# passing extra param in rails using check_box_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I want to add some extra parameters (categories) when filling my standard form for `Event` model. They are not in my events table (I have table `categories_events` and `hmbtm` in both `Events` and `Category` models). Here is my code for _form :

```
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <div class="field">
  <%= check_box_tag(:category, category.id) %>
  <%= label_tag( :category, "#{category.name}" ) %>
  </div>

  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>

  <% end %>
```

I'm passing categories in `new` action - it's simple Category.all

Here is my code in events controller

```
def new
    @event = Event.new
    @categories = Category.all
  end

def create
    @event = Event.new(event_params)
    @category_id = Category.find(params[:category])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @event.save
        format.html { redirect_to @event, notice: 'Event was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @event }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Later I want to put category_id and event_id into categories_events but I have NoMethodError

```
undefined method `category_id' for #<Event:0x374c268>
```

and @event.safe is the problem

Parameters look like this

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"stL+sdIhxttrk3KjkLJsuCXubjaDpNBbrLYtpjv8clw=",
 "event"=>{"name"=>"asdsa",
 "place"=>"asdas",
 "description"=>"dsadsa"},
 "commit"=>"Create Event",
 "category"=>"2"}
```

I think that the problem is in too many parameters in new(event_params) but looking at brackets in parameters tells me that it shouldn't be a problem to make it acceptable for rails.

Error stacktrace:
http://pastebin.com/kQK1fni6

Updated event_params

```
def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, :place, :description, :category_ids)
    end
```

Comment: Could you please share `event_params` method and the error stacktrace.

Comment: def event_params
      params.require(:event).permit(:name, :place, :description, :category)
    end
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:32:in `block in create'
app/controllers/events_controller.rb:31:in `create'
line 31: respond_to
line 32: if @event.save

Comment: Could you please share the complete error stacktrace for the error you received. And add it to the question and not in comment. Its more readable there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adjust your check_box_tag to the following:

```
<%= check_box_tag("event[category_ids][]", category.id, @event.categories.include?(category)) %>
<%= label_tag("event[category_ids][]", category.name) %>
```

One more thing, you'll have to add category_ids to your whitelisted attributes.

Comment: Hey. Thanks for help, but now i have "Couldn't find Category without an ID" Error. Problem lies in
@category_id = Category.find(params[:category_ids])

Comment: What does that line do? Can you remove it?

Comment: OK I have the aswer - after your explanation I forget to change validation (ad 's' to category_ids). To answer your question I need it to add category_id and event_id to join table categories_events. Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: Hmm, just a quick tip: if your relationship is setup like this: `has_and_belongs_to_many :categories`, and when you do this: `@event.category_ids = [1,2,3]`, this will _automatically_ add records for you to the join table. Check `has_and_belongs_to_many` section in the following link: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

Answer (score 1):

To resolve `Couldn't find Category without an ID`
Replace

```
@category_id = Category.find(params[:category_ids])
```

with

```
@category_id = Category.find(params[:event][:category_ids])
```

If you check the `params` hash you'll see that due to the update in checkbox code(as suggested by H-man), `category_ids` would be part of `params[:event]` keys value.

Comment: Yep but from what I can see He just enable me to pass more categories (which is great) but Im back with "undefined method `category_id' for #<Event:0x4f9bff0>"
I did everything including whitelisted attributes. By error stack do you mean that? http://pastebin.com/kQK1fni6

Comment: @user3344159 You are right. Thats what I meant by stacktrace.

Comment: @user3344159 What does your `params` look like now? Please update it in your question as the params in original question does not reflect the change.

Comment: @user3344159 Hope H-man and me get a up vote from you. We worked so hard. :)

Comment: Yeah sure but I need more rep ;)